# Uncaught SyntaxError jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using following code

```
$(document).ready({
  if ($('.help-block').text().length > 0) {
    setTimeout(function(){$('.help-block').text("");},3000);
  }
});
```

But getting the following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

On the following line

```
if ($('.help-block').text().length > 0) {
```

I can't resolve it. Help needed

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { your statement  here});  use this syntax for  ready function

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because you're providing an object to `$(document).ready()` instead of a function. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // note function() here
  if ($('.help-block').text().length > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.help-block').text(''); // you could use empty() here instead
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```